# Angular ngGrid pagination forward buttons won't disable

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I've a json with some data stored on `$scope.data`.

**JS**

```
 $scope.pagingOptions = {
        pageSize: 5,
        currentPage: 1
    };

$scope.setPagingData = function (data, page, pageSize) {
        var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize, page * pageSize);
        $scope.myData = pagedData;
        $scope.pagingOptions.totalServerItems = data.length;
    };

$scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
            $scope.setPagingData($scope.data, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.pagingOptions.pageSize);
        }
    }, true);

$scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        enableRowSelection: false,
        enablePaging: true,
        showFooter: true,
        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

**Problem**

"myData" has 8 results. First page shows 5, second page shows 3, BUT forward button doesnt disable when there are no more results in array "myData".
Otherwise, back button works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was missing `totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems'`

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'myData',
            enableRowSelection: false,
            enablePaging: true,
            totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
            showFooter: true,
            pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions
        };
```